# Magnetic force on a metallic block

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was wondering is there any formula to calculate the magnetic force exerted on a metallic block in a magnetic field?
Let's say there is a coil of wire with length=L, area=A, and turns=N.
A metallic cylinder with permeability=μ (it is ferromagnetic but doesn't have its own magnetic dipole) is partially inside the coil.
If the current=I is passed through the coil, what will be the force that pulls the metal block inside the coil? Is there a formula for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are equations for the amount of force experienced by a ferromagnetic material in an external field - e.g. see [Magnetic Force on a Ferromagenetic Material](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131885)